# spanning cells interfere with the td:nth-child(even) logic

Tags: html, css

Im trying to build a timetable that includes a vertical cell-spans because u-know-why, but the (intentionally)missing cells are not counted in my :nth-child(even) - rule, which bugs the visual display of the table. To further elaborate, pay close attention to the third cell right of the spanned cell:

http://jsfiddle.net/WbtvT/

Is there any way to make the css count the missing(spanned) cells as well? Or maybe some jquery magic?

Answer (score 0):

There is no flexible solution here. You have to hardcode the box you want to shade yourself, if that is acceptable?

```
.shade {background-color:silver;} Add this line in CSS
```

Ass the TD that is going to be affected the class="shade"

Do you want a flexible solution? What is your criteria

[Here is jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WbtvT/30/)

Comment: it just has to be as flexible as possible since all the data is generated server side

Comment: Since you will be resizing the table TD's on server side, you can do this for this one particular cell too. But I understand it will get more complicated, if the entry was in the first column. You need a proper algorithm

Comment: The working hours are pre-set and there are five days in the week which implies no aditional columns or rows are required to my layout. so if a solution arises given the framework - ill take it

Comment: I was already guessing that some kind of fun algorithm would solve the matter, but since i'm the designer, i'm trying to open as least as possible new challenges to the programmers.

Comment: leave this glitch as it is, doesn't not look that bad.

Comment: Oh, but it does :} this is just a stripped down preview. What im actually composing relays on this glitch. Thanx for showing interest though.